# How to insert a folder inside an existing jar file using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy script.

I have a jar file "First.jar" having the following folder structure.

First.jar

```
 Automation
 site
     Upgrade
```

for example this is the structure of my jar file. I have a folder structure like:

D:\Site\Upgrade

I am writing a Groovy script that will search the jar file and replace the folder "Upgrade" from my drive into the jar file if present. If the upgrade folder not present it will copy the upgrade folder from my D drive to the jar file.

I am very much new to Groovy, can anyone help me to complete this task. Please give some code or links I can refer.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe better solution is to insert folder in project structure before build? Then groovy will copy this folder automatically during build.

Comment: Yes you are right, But my task to place the folder inside the jar file using Groovy script, means copy folder from system D drive into the jar file.

Comment: Are you aware that the jar is a zip compressed file?